# Is it possible to iterate over a list and skip certain elements?

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I imported a .xml with two columns (name, quantity). I want to write a function that groups the names into groups whose quantity equals 50. For example given: x - 10, y - 35, z - 42, n - 5, m - 3, and p - 5. The program would return "x,y,n" and "z,m,p". It would not return "x,y,p" since n occurs first. Additionally, after the first iteration of the loop, it did not use z, m or p, but would consider them on the second iteration, while ignoring the names already used by the first iteration.

For such a small example, I'm able to create this code with my limited knowledge. However, I need to apply this to over 1000 names and for this, my code, which consists of mostly while and if/else loops is too inefficient.

Just a little more information:
The code essentially is broken down into three parts:
(A) If sum reaches 50 -> output
(B) if less than 50, keep going until (A)
(C) if greater than 50, ignore the number the program just added and try the next one in the list and test for condition (B) until (A) is reached.

I can mostly figure out (A) and (B) but am struggling with efficiently executing part (C).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It is mush easier to help if you show the code you have developed so far, as a minimum complete working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your goal is to find tuples that exactly add up to 50, the solution will be a bit more complicated than your current approach.
Consider these numbers:

```
x  20
y  25
z  10
m  15
n   8
p  22
```

Your algorithm would first add x=20 and y=25 and then walk through the rest of the list without finding a matching 5 that would complete this tuple. The correct solution would be "x,n,p" and "y,z,m".

A working algorithm would collect chains of entries which sum to less than 50, and stop one iteration through the list when one chain reaches 50. The chain elements would then be removed from the list, and the process repeated until no tuples can be found.

Python code as promised: (pardon the style, this is my first python program :-) )

```
class ListElement:
    def __init__(self, name, value):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + "=" + self.value.__str__()

class ChainElement:
    def __init__(self, prev, listElement):
        self.prev = prev
        self.listElement = listElement
        if prev:
            self.value = listElement.value + prev.value
        else:
            self.value = listElement.value

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.prev:
            return self.prev.__repr__() + "," + self.listElement.__repr__()
        else:
            return self.listElement.__repr__()

    def removeAllFrom(self, list):
        list.remove(self.listElement)
        if self.prev:
            self.prev.removeAllFrom(list)

list = []
list.append(ListElement("x", 20))
list.append(ListElement("y", 25))
list.append(ListElement("z", 10))
list.append(ListElement("m", 15))
list.append(ListElement("n",  8))
list.append(ListElement("p", 22))

def find_chain():
    chains = [ChainElement(None, list[0])]

    for le in list[1:]:
        new_chains = []
        for ce in chains:
            new_chain = ChainElement(ce, le)
            if new_chain.value == 50:
                return new_chain
            elif new_chain.value < 50:
                new_chains.append(new_chain)
        chains.extend(new_chains);
    return None

while list:
    tuple = find_chain()
    if tuple:
        print "Found:", tuple
        tuple.removeAllFrom(list)
    else:
        print
        print "Residue:", list
        break
```

There are combinations of values for which this program will not find a complete solution even though one exists, understanding and fixing this is left as an exercise to the reader...

Comment: Oh I see, since I had been using hard code to see if it would work, I hadn't considered that. Do you have any suggestions to help get me started on the solution you suggested? I'm a novice at Python and feel way over my head. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm a novice at python myself, so I'd have to work on this example quite a bit, too. I could write down the algorithm in pseudocode (or Smalltalk) but you'd have to write working python code from that...

Comment: Sure! Pseudocode would be great, I think I could manage from there. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tomorrow - and it'll be python, so I have an incentive to learn it :-)